# Pull values from array to a new single array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array like this:

```
pa: [{ 
  id: 1,
  sa: [ 1, 2, 3 ]
}, {
  id: 2,
  sa: [ 1, 2, 3 ]
}, {
  id: 3,
}]
```

Some of the objects contain an `sa` array and some don't. I want to create a new array that contains all the numbers of `sa` in a new single array

I have tried this but it will add in multiple arrays

```
for (let i = 0; i < pa.length; i++) {
  if (pa[i].sa!== undefined && pa[i]?.sa) {
    f.push(p[i]?.sa?.map(a=> a.id));
  }
}
```

i want the final array to be

```
newArray = [1,2,3,1,2,3]
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with React. I suggest you remove the `reactjs` tag

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge/flatten an array of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take a flat mapping with a destructuring with optional array.

```js
const
    data = { pa: [{ id: 1, sa: [1, 2, 3] }, { id: 2, sa: [1, 2, 3] }, { id: 3 }] },
    result = data.pa.flatMap(({ sa = [] }) => sa);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get a single array by just applying `.flat()` to your result.

A simpler version of your code:

```
const newArray = pa.map(e => e.sa ?? []).flat();
```

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat ironically, the approach with for loops will run a lot quicker than the other suggestions because it doesn't create intermediate copies of the array, and is subjectively just as readable.

```
for (let i = 0, sa; i < pa.length; i++)
  if (sa = pa[i].sa)
    for (let j = 0; j < sa.length; j++)
      newArray.push(sa[j]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sharing an optimized answer  as few answers are already their. Just using your approach correctly so that you know how your logic can be used.

```
let output = [];
let k = pa.map(item => {
    if (item.sa) {
        output = [...output, ...item.sa];
    }
})
```